# Enums with numeric names

Tags: python, enums

The following doesn't work in Python:

```
class MemorySize(int, Enum):
    "1024" = 1024
    "2048" = 2048
```

So what would be the closest way to do this without having to type the entire number out in words and make it type safe?

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Tip: `int, Enum` can be replaced with `IntEnum`

Comment: How doesn't work? What does "…type the entire number out in words and make it type safe" even mean?

Comment: Follks shouldn't have to look at answers to understand the question being asked.

Comment: @martineau A lot of people did understand the question so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Otherwise it wouldn't of been answered and accepted.

Comment: One answer does not a lot of people make.

Comment: @martineau It was a sufficient answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum):

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, constant values. Within an enumeration, the members can be compared by identity, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.

So, enum members should be `symbolic names`, not string literals.

If you want to use numbers as names you can prefix it with `_` or `m_`, because private attributes [start with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Also, you can use [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) for integer enums.

```
from enum import IntEnum


class MemorySize(IntEnum):
    m_1024 = 1024
    m_2048 = 2048

print(MemorySize.m_1024.value)
```

Output

```
1024
```

Also, you can omit comma here `"1024" = 1024,`.

Actually `1024,` is a tuple with one element `(1024, )` and `1024` is just int. I was just curious, why you can pass tuple as well as int to Enum attribute.

I found out that the value of `IntEnum` attribute passes to `int` constructor. Before that it transforms args into tuple in `EnumMeta.__new__`

```
if not isinstance(value, tuple):
    args = (value, )
else:
    args = value
```

You can pass to `int` constructor second argument, the base:
because `int("ff", 16) == 255`. Or just use string constant instead of int because `int("123") == 123`.

So, you can use `IntEnum` values with any number system like this (Although I don't think it's good way to use it in practice)

```
class WeiredEnum(IntEnum):
    m_255 = "ff", 16
    m_256 = "256"

print(WeiredEnum.m_255.value)
print(type(WeiredEnum.m_256.value))
```

```
> 255
> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: please provide explanation why your solution with _underscore_ works.

Comment: @raiyan22 Because `_1024` is [valid python identifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-python-identifiers)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it *in the answer*. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Must of use the ".value" at the end?

Comment: @MrFuppes: As a [famous transcendentalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Reliance) once wrote: _"A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds"_ (which PEP 8 [repeats](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) and goes on to say "However, know when to be inconsistent…").

Comment: @martineau yeah that was kind of stupid, hope it didn't cause you physical pain. Guess I was a bit perplexed by the question, why one should use a number to represent that number in an enum.

Comment: @MrFuppes: Hard to say what the OP is planning on doing because they haven't revealed why or how they want their approach to "work", only that it "doesn't".

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do that!**

Analyzing it, I realized that in this case **it actually doesn't make sense to have an enum**. If you have an enum of an integer that receives integer it is better not to have the enum at all and work only with the integer values, defining only the typing to limit it.

You can use the [Literal type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) that was introduced in **PEP 586** as a way to indicate that a variable must have a set of certain values.

```
from typing import Literal
ex: StatusCode = Literal[404, 200, 500]
```